# Docker container, ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, with CORS AllowAnyOrigin

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, cors, webapi

I am just starting to work with Docker and I want to connect my Web API to it on ASP. When I configure the CORS policy in Program.cs of my API, if I specify restricted addresses for example:

```
builder
 .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5256 ")
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod();
```

then the container is normally created and normally launched in the future. But if I specify

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
```

Then when you start the container, there is no page and gives the result
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Can someone explain, why it's happening ?
Here is my Program.cs file:

```
using System;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();



var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Container working, but when i click on link, it's just ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSDPJ.png)

I tried to use

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowLocalhost", builder =>
    {
        builder
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5256")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work at all.
I also tried to add

```
 .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true),
```

but it also didn't help.

Comment: Make sure you leave no trailing whitespace in `"http://localhost:5256 "`.

Answer (score 0):

I would register it early in the middleware normally above the swagger devlopment environment as it might handle request before cors is applied

Comment: Short and not certain might be added as comment